# Rails assets pipeline with bootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, less, assets, pipeline, precompile

I know that the issue was talked about few times but I still can't find one proper way.

I use less and I have bootstrap.less (no gem), global.less, variables.less, login.less. All in app/assests/stylesheet directory.

My application.less looks like this:

```
 *= require 'bootstrap'
 *= require 'global'
 *= require 'login'
```

and including:

```
 <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
```

I was trying to use: `rake assets:clean assets:precompile`
I was trying to @import in many ways

Issues I have:
login.less and global.less don't see variables until I @import it.
I can't override bootstrap directives without !important and it confuses me so much. Even if I import them in correct order to my application.less it still generates one big application.css where bootstrap is at the end. I don;t get it.

I want to have my less files in correct order to override it as I want. It will be good if it compiles to one file to make browser load website faster (I though that `require` does it but it doesn't look so)

Please advice what should I do. I lost my day on this issue.

Comment: You can `@import 'bootstrap/variables'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change bootstrap vars and use variables/mixins across the files you should create a file called `bootstrap_and_overrides.less` there you import all your other files and bootstrap in correct order.

This single file should be required in application.css (plus any other files, like query-ui.css, etc). You should not include bootstrap files in application.css though.

You could also just it `application.css.less` but I had some problems with that approach.

Answer (score 0):

I've done what you said.

My application.css:

```
 *= require general
```

general.less:

```
@import 'bootstrap';    
@import 'variables';
@import 'global';
@import 'login';
```

and in global I have:

```
  border-radius: 0px;
```

which doesn't work without !important because it's being overwritten by bootstrap somehow. This is the only issue because the rest works OK...

...I was writing the rest of the post while...
Oh my god. Eureka:D I used:

```
input{ border-radius: 0;}
```

but in bootstrap there is:

```
.btn{ border-radius: 4px;}
```

And this is because I can't override it without important! Jesus...

Anyway, thank you Michal for solution because it solved all the other issues.

Comment: however I have issues with caching:/

Comment: fixed by adding depend_on. The problem is that @imported less files are not being recompiled for some reason and I needed to add depend_on variables etc to bootstrap_and_overrides.less